# 2 Trigonometric equations $3\sin B +4 \cos C=6$ and $4\sin C+3 \cos B=1$, show that $\sin(B+C)=0.5)$

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

I've been experimenting with the double angle formula but I get a result that is inconsistent with the question. Can anyone give me a hint towards the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that you want to solve for $\sin(B + C) = \sin B \cos C + \cos B \sin C$.  Now I would advise you to take the square of your equations, since the first one will then have  a $\sin B \cos C$ term, and the second one will have a $\cos B \sin C$ term, and try to proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

$$(3\sin B+4\cos C)^2=6^2=9\sin^2 B+24\sin B \cos C+16\cos^2 C=36$$
$$(4\sin C+3\cos B)^2=1^2=16\sin^2C+24\sin C\cos B+9\cos^2 B=1$$
Add the two equations 
$$16+9+24(\sin B\cos C+\sin C\cos B)=37$$
$$\sin B\cos C+\sin C\cos B=1/2$$
$$\sin(B+C)=1/2$$